# ссылки на картинке

Tags: css, ссылки, веб-дизайн

Добрый день.
Подскажите каким образом реализовать задуманное.

Пришла в голову идея сделать схему-каталог (по типу схемы метро).
То есть картинка - карта с 20(например пунктами)точками.
Выглядит как схема метро (в идеале вообще background).
Каждая точка(станция) является ссылкой.
проблема даже не в том как это сделать, а как прикрепить к конкретной точке на картинке и при этом что бы при масштабировании оно не сползло.
Отдаленно как раз должно напоминать http://mosmetro.ru/metro-map/ это.
Подскажите открытые примеры если есть или хоть направление. 
Спасибо.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Есть 2 варианта решения вашей проблемы:

1 Вариант - вы используете jpg\png, тогда вам необходимо воспользоваться возможностью задавать area для картинки пример можете посмотреть [здесь](http://html.cita.illinois.edu/text/map/map-example.php) и [здесь](http://davidlynch.org/projects/maphilight/docs/demo_simple.html) и уже при нажатии на area вы можете делать все что душе угодно

2 Вариант - использовать SVG для схемы метро. Тогда вы можете задать каждому элементу на картинке id (или, предпочтительно, некий атрибут) и уже при нажатии\наведении\любом_другом_событии делать всё что вашей душе угодно с помощью js+css - для SVG (если она вставлена в сам html, а не картинкой) будут работать все селекторы как в css, так и в js.

Лично для меня, 2-й вариант наиболее предпочтителен, так как в первом варианте еще может всплыть проблема с адаптивностью, да и впринципе вырисовывать area на картинках - довольно трудозатратно, в SVG проще на этапе её рисования сразу необходимые аттрибуты прописать и всё. Да и к тому же, на сайте, приведенном вами в качестве примера, используется как раз-таки 2-й вариант

Answer (score 2):

Маркеры надо позиционировать на карте абсолютно в процентах. При этом очень важно держать соотношение сторон карты, см. как сделано в сниппете. Само соотношение сторон задается padding-bottom.

```css
.map {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 0;
  padding-bottom: 50%;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.map img {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  top: -80%; // выставляем видимый участок карты
  left: 0;
}

.marker {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  color: red;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
}

.paris {
  left: 27%;
  top: 63%;
}

.moscow {
  left: 80%;
  top: 18%;
}
```

```html
<div class="map">
  <img src="http://mapeurope.ru/wp-content/uploads/konturnaya-karta-evropy-10klass.jpg">
  <div class="marker paris">x</div>
  <div class="marker moscow">x</div>
</div>
```

Свойство top: -80% выставляет видимый участок для данной конкретной карты и не является обязательным.

Comment: Извиняюсь что так долго отсутствовал. 
хм. Интересный вариант. Действительно, это наверное самый простой способ реализовать мою задумку. Благодарю.

Comment: Хорошее решение.... Что ж ни кто не оценил....

Comment: @Air https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/51/unsung-hero?userid=220220 бггг)))

Comment: Ну хоть система оценивает)))