# Позиционирование точек на карте

Tags: html, css

Есть блок

```
    <div class="container">
            <h1>Заголовок</h1>
            <div class="black_map">              
                <img class="tool tool-1" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="текст" src="images/tooltip.png" alt="">
                <img class="tool tool-2" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="текст" src="images/tooltip.png" alt="">  
                <img class="tool tool-3" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" 
 title="текст" src="images/tooltip.png" alt="">
                <img class="tool tool-4" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" 
                 title="текст" src="images/tooltip.png" alt="">  
                <img class="tool tool-5" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" 
                title="текст" src="images/tooltip.png" alt=""> 
                ... 
                <img class="tool tool-13" data-html="true" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" src="images/tooltip.png" alt="">                     
            </div>
        </div>
```

CSS

```
 .black_map {
    position: relative;
    background: url(../images/map.png) 100% 100% no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    height: 587px;
    }
    .tool {
    position: absolute;
    }

    .tool-1 {
    bottom: 207px;
    left: 73px;
    }
    .container{max-width:1140px}
```

Вопрос - нужно строго спозиционировать точки на карте. Я уже исчерпал всю свою фантазию как это сделать, чтобы при уменьшении размеров окна точки не смещались.

Comment: _чтобы при уменьшении размеров окна точки не смещались._  - если можно сделать все так грубо, поставьте статичный бек и сделайте все абсолютом. Плюс не `background-size: cover` , а `background-size: 100% 100%`

Comment: Вот тут я давал ответ на точно такой же вопрос: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708192/220220