# Получение адаптивного YouTube видео при фиксированной высоте

Tags: javascript, iframe, видео, youtube, youtube-api

Подскажите, как получить адаптивное видео из youtube в iframe, если есть ограничение по высоте для блока.

```js
window.onload = function(){
  
    var blockForFrame = $(".bl_game__bigScreen"),
        heightForVideoIframe = blockForFrame.outerHeight(true),
        widthForVideoIframe = Math.ceil(heightForVideoIframe * 16 / 9);

    $(".bl_video__iframe").css({"height": heightForVideoIframe, "width": widthForVideoIframe});


}
```

```css
.bl_game__bigScreen {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 480px;
  background-color: #000;
  vertical-align: top;
}

.bl_game__videoWrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 480px;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 3;
}

.bl_video {
  position:relative;
  padding-bottom:56.25%; /*пропорции видео 16:9 */
  padding-top:25px;
  height:0;
}

.bl_video__iframe {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
}

.bl_game__wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  color: #fff;
  z-index: 2;
}

.bl_game__img {
  margin-right: 4vw;
}

.bl_game__nav {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
}

.gamePage_title {
  position: relative;
  display: initial;
  max-width: 550px;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: 48px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
  text-shadow: 0 8px 12px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.36);
}

.bl_game__desc {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 24px;
  max-height: 140px;
  overflow-y: auto;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 16px;
  letter-spacing: 0.09em;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  color: #FFF;
}

.bl_game__buttons {
  margin-top: 24px;
}

.btn_playGame {
  width: 184px;
  height: 56px;
  background-color: #000;
  border-radius: 44px;
  margin-right: 24px;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  outline: none;
  transition: .15s all;
}

.btn_watchVideo {
  width: 184px;
  height: 56px;
  background: #FFF;
  border-radius: 44px;
  cursor: pointer;
  line-height: 23px;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #000;
  outline: none;
  transition: .2s all;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 991px) {

  .bl_game__bigScreen {
min-height: 690px;
  }
  .bl_game__wrapper {
flex-direction: column;
  }

  .bl_game__img {
margin: 0 auto;
display: block;
  }
  .bl_game__nav {
margin-top: 10px;
text-align: center;
  }

  .gamePage_title {
margin: 32px auto;
  }

}

@media only screen and (max-width: 520px) {

  .bl_game__bigScreen {
min-height: 810px;
  }

  .bl_game__desc {
max-width: 370px;
margin: 24px auto;
  }

  .btn_playGame,
  .btn_watchVideo {
display: block;
margin: 24px auto;
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="bl_game">

  <img class="bl_game__bigScreen" src="https://baconmockup.com/1600/512" alt="mainImage-slot">
  <div class="bl_game__videoWrapper">
    
    <div class="bl_video">
      <iframe class="bl_video__iframe" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/hTWKbfoikeg?version=3&rel=0&loop=1&autoplay=1&modestbranding=1&showinfo=0&controls=0&showinfo=0" allowfullscreen="" frameborder="0"></iframe>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  
  <div class="bl_game__wrapper">
    <img class="bl_game__img" src="https://placekitten.com/302/250
" alt="gameLogo">

    <div class="bl_game__nav">
      <h1 class="gamePage_title">Game Title</h1>

      <div class="bl_game__desc">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Laborum eveniet nesciunt consequuntur distinctio neque esse, ut dolor illum cupiditate. Veniam.</div>
      <div class="bl_game__buttons">
        <button class="btn_playGame" data-href="" type="button">Run Demo</button>
        <button class="btn_watchVideo" data-href="" type="button">Play Video</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>




</div>
```

По заданию, я ограничен по высоте для видео. (Видео контент должен перекрывать блок с информацией об игре. И быть position:absolute;)

Я понимаю, для того, чтобы видео смотрелось без искажений - оно должно быть в пропорции 16/9, для этого я скриптом получаю размер блока на момент загрузки и дальше задаю значения для iframe (ширину и высоту), но этот метод не работает для планшетов и мобильных. (Вообще-то мне хотелось бы, чтобы видео было на всю ширину экрана, но я не могу придумать концептуально правильного решения).

Comment: Посмотрите мой ответ, где я показывал, как держать соотношение сторон https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/708192/220220

Comment: Боюсь что мне ваш вариант не подходит. У меня родитель, iframe с видио, уже имеет position:absolute/

Comment: Ну и что. А видео, кстати, пишется через Е. Устал исправлять вопрос.